# MM2 offset synchronization when consumer group not created on target due to non activity

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have secondary cluster, that till disaster has no consumers.
while DR this cluster need be consumed by same consumer groups as on Primary and it requried to consume with same offset

if to set sync.group.offsets.enabled: true
will offset infromation of specific sconsumer group be synced,
even if no consumer group created yet on secondary cluster?

Kafka Improvement Proposal (KIP) 382: This KIP introduces MirrorMaker 2 and provides an overview of its features. It mentions that MirrorMaker 2 can sync consumer group offsets along with the replicated messages

Maybe someone had tried it practically?

Comment: What is your kafka version ?

Comment: version 3.4 for now

Comment: 3.5.1 and 3.6.0 have improvements in MM2, if you check release notes. You can run the new version separately from the broker machines (this is recommended installation pattern, anyway)

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Kafka **2.7.0** and above, **the answer is yes**: if sync.group.offsets.enabled: true, MM2  will translate group offsets automatically from the MM2 checkpoints topic into the "__consumer_offsets" topic on the destination cluster.

This an improvement that allow consumers and stream applications migrate from source to target cluster transparently, so that when the consumer and stream applications switch to the target cluster, it will resume to consume from where it left off at source cluster.